How to find burned component?
I have a Iomega Ix4 300D network storage and I try to power on with 48 V adapter but I did see its only support 19 V so its burned. I want replace that component DC to DC converter like a 8 spos leg-
It mentions RT828---
GPS



The PCB is probably ruined.  Look at the dark area of discolouration south-west of the chip in the second photo, to me that looks like damage on the inner layers.

Probably Richtek RT8289.
Link to datasheet: Link

Image source, datasheet at https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT8289/DS8289-02.pdf

where i get like this component?

Recommendations where to buy is off-topic here. Please take the Tour. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour
